# Cannot open web interface using react native in vs code

Tags: node.js, react-native

I created the react native app with expo CLI using the react official documentation. I've seen a few others have the same problem with this step and have solved them, but I've done everything and it still doesn't appear to work. Appreciate the help guys.

```
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

I do want to start the react native development app using expo cli in vs code. I am expecting to run the app using npm start

Comment: what your node version? In the latest version of Expo, node version 16+ is needed.

Comment: Do you have OpenSSL installed? if not, try installing it.

Comment: Yes I am using the latest version of expo which was installed using cmd and my node version is 18.14.0 LTS @raman

Comment: No I didn't install yet? where can i find it? Thx @Razor

Comment: 1. Download the relevant OpenSSL binary distribution from the OpenSSL download page: https://www.openssl.org/source/

2. Extract the files from the archive you downloaded.

3. Open a command prompt and navigate to the directory where you extracted the OpenSSL files.

4. Run the following: ./config 

5. Run the following: make 

6. Run the following: make test 

7. Run the following: make install 

8. Run the following: ldconfig 

9. To check that OpenSSL has been installed, run the following command: openssl version 

10. You should see the version of OpenSSL.